# iOS 14, avplayer just plays audio with black screen

Tags: ios, avplayer, ios14

My application was working just fine before the iOS 14. its working fine on some devices now but in iPhone xs and x avplayer isn't working properly. I'm playing videos from url but it is just playing audio with a black screen.

Comment: Can you please show your code.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/VgXZvk.jpg

Comment: Argh, objective-c code! But try `controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;` (frame could be different).